# Remove a dictionary if all the keys has empty values in it?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, ienumerable

I am having a  `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. I need to remove the dictionary from this list if all the keys has empty values in it. Here is my code, and the sample.

```
 foreach (int rowval in rowscol)
{
   Dictionary<string, object> Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   foreach (Contracts.CommonDataField field in finalColumns)
   {
   var valList = record.CommonDataValues.FirstOrDefault(row => row.RowID == rowval && row.FieldName == field.FieldName);
   if (valList != null)
   {
     string value = valList.RecordFieldData;
     Data.Add(field.FieldName, value);
   }
  }
 finaldata.Add(Data);
}
```

I need to remove this

**[image: Sample:]**

Sample dictionary with data,

[image]

Comment: Why do you add it to the list if you want to remove it later anyway?

Comment: The problem is sometimes some  keys may have values, there is no way to check since the data is added dynamically.

Comment: Are you looking for a more elegant solution than the obvious 'iterate over list, create collection of empty dictionaries and then do a second sweep to remove them'?

Comment: @Sajeetharan You can check before adding the dictionary to the list.

Comment: @user469104 any soultion which should not contain a dictionary with all keys having empty values

Comment: why is the dictionary is of type <string,object> ? can it be of type <string, typeof(RecordFieldData)> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you add it to the list if you want to remove it later anyway?

However, since the key is a string and the value is also a string this should work:

```
finaldata = finaldata
   .Where(d => d.Values.Cast<string>().Any(str => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)))
   .ToList();
```

or

```
finaldata.RemoveAll(d => d.Values.Cast<string>().All(String.IsNullOrEmpty));
```

If it's always a string i'd use a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` in the first place. If the type of the value can be something different you could use:

```
finaldata.RemoveAll(d => d.Values.All(obj => obj == null || obj.ToString() == ""));
```

Comment: Actually the value is an `object` in the dictionary.

Comment: @juharr: therefore i've used `Cast<string>`(it is a string if you look at the code).

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```
 foreach (int rowval in rowscol)
{
   bool hasNonNullValue = false;
   Dictionary<string, object> Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   foreach (Contracts.CommonDataField field in finalColumns)
   {
   var valList = record.CommonDataValues.FirstOrDefault(row => row.RowID == rowval && row.FieldName == field.FieldName);
   if (valList != null)
   {
     string value = valList.RecordFieldData;
     Data.Add(field.FieldName, value);
     if (value != null) {
        hasNonNullValue = true;
     }
   }
  }
  if (hasNonNullValue) {
    finaldata.Add(Data);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (int rowval in rowscol)
{
   Dictionary<string, object> Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   bool empty = true;
   foreach (Contracts.CommonDataField field in finalColumns)
   {
       var valList = record.CommonDataValues.FirstOrDefault(row => row.RowID == rowval && row.FieldName == field.FieldName);
       if (valList != null)
       {
           string value = valList.RecordFieldData;
           Data.Add(field.FieldName, value);
           if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) empty = false;
       }
   }
   if (!empty) finaldata.Add(Data);
}
```